# TypeError: expect(...).toBe is not a function

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I am using this code to do a test, the `demo.js` code look like this:

```
var expect = require('chai').expect

describe('Array', function() {
    describe('indexOf()', function() {
        it("dovrebbe tornare -1 quando l'elemento non è presente", function() {
            expect([1,2,3].indexOf(4)).to.equal(-1)
            expect("d").toBe( 'function' );
        })
    })
})
```

when I run this command to execute the test:

```
istanbul cover _mocha ./test/demo.js
```

shows error like this:

```
[dolphin@MiWiFi-R4CM-srv]~/Documents/GitHub/translation.js% istanbul cover _mocha ./test/demo.js


  Array
    indexOf()
      1) dovrebbe tornare -1 quando l'elemento non è presente


  0 passing (6ms)
  1 failing

  1) Array
       indexOf()
         dovrebbe tornare -1 quando l'elemento non è presente:
     TypeError: expect(...).toBe is not a function
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/demo.js:7:26)
```

what should I do fix this problem?

- node version: 10
- "istanbul": "^0.4.5",

I also tried to install jest(`npm install --save-dev jest`), but still did not fix this problem. I think maybe the chai did not contain the toBe, which expect lib should I use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: expect(...).to.be is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33992967/typeerror-expect-to-be-is-not-a-function)

Comment: No, I have already read the question, he is `to.be` I am is `toBe`, that is different. @fatemehyadollahzadeh

Comment: Since you are using Chai, the correct syntax is `expect(...).to.be`. There are other libraries (like Jasmine) that allow you to write `expect(...).toBe`.

Comment: This show `ReferenceError: expect is not defined` when I use `jasmine`.@GOTO0 when I use the chai, I could not found the `toBe` function, when I am use the jasmine, the code shows could not found the `expect`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can set "expect" as a variable. Plus, "var" has been discarded.

The two "expects" inside the function block have nothing to do with

```
   var expect = require('chai').expect
```

If you console.log '**expect("d")**', I think you'd get **undefined** -- that's is to say, "toBe(...)" cannot be used on an undefined variable, which is why you've got the error.

By the way, there is a "d" inside **expect("d")** -- what is the "d"?

No definite answer can be given based on the info you showed above.

Comment: I just want to find the right way to use expect. @William Hou

Comment: For that, you have to learn UNIT TESTING. "expect" is not variable. It's a major part in UNIT TESTING. To be frank, I think you've just started to do UNIT TESTING, am I right?

Comment: yes, I am to do an unit test.@William Hou

Comment: What I meant was that, you're NEW to UNIT TESTING, I guess?

Comment: If you are NEW to unit testing, you have to learn it first. I beg your pardon, but yours is not the right way.

Comment: yes, I have never write or using unit test in javascript before. I am always using unit test in java. @ William Hou Is this problem hard to solve? I just want to test an api in the client side, I am write a lib.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238739/discussion-between-william-hou-and-dolphin).